# Add an expandable text box to every post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am building a comment system and have loaded a bunch of comments to a page, then have generated a reply box for each. Below is what my reply box looks like, but there are many identical ones on each page. As you can see, the first portion is a div that contains a toggle (show/hide) for the reply box.

I am posting because I cannot get the reply toggle to fire.

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
    <a href="#" id="reply-toggle">
        <span class="text">Reply</span>
        <i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="reply-div" class="col-sm-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset='UTF-8' data-parsley-validate novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ticket-message" class="col-sm-1 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" id="new_post_textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Try to be as specific as possible when posting!"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                    <button id="submit_reply_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit Reply</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$("#reply-toggle a").click(function() {
                alert("running");
                $('#reply-div').slideToggle("slow");
            )};
```

I recognize I am not very good in jquery, so I am sure it's something simple, however, I also recognize that I will have to use jquery(closest) to only toggle the reply box associated with the proper comment thread. I have not gotten to this step yet, but it would be greatly appreciated If I could receive some guidance in regards to that as well.

Sincere thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#reply-toggle', function() {
    $(this).closest('.col-sm-offset-1').next('#reply-div').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

edit:added a period to the col-sm-offset-1 class

Comment: thanks a bunch. It fires now but not toggling the window. I am pretty confident I can figure out that part though... I'll let you know if I get it, and will edit your answer if necessary.

Comment: Hey, just needed a period before the col-sm-offset-1 class. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your link selector does not match anything. `$("#reply-toggle a")` will return all `<a>` tags that have a parent with ID `reply-toggle`.

You should change this to simply `$("#reply-toggle")`.

Edit: As an aside, you say you have multiple of these Reply buttons - I would strongly recommend you change the ID selector to a class selector as browsers expect only one element with a specific ID per page.

Answer (score 0):

`"#reply-toggle a"` looks for `<a>` elements within an element that has id "reply-toggle". Maybe `$("a#reply-toggle")` would fix your firing issue?

You might want to generate a specific id for each reply toggle and div, say `reply-toggle-1`and `reply-div-1`. However, this approach needs a `click()`defined for each toggle. Use class declarations instead (i.e. not `id="reply-toggle"`, but `class="reply-toggle"`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have never done something like this but I did initially consider that a possibility but thought that would get pretty messy with potentially a bunch of comments. Why are classes better in this instance?

Comment: ID should be assigned to a single element. A class can appear as many times as you wish. If you want to access several elements, you can do it with one line of code `$(".my-element")` instead of `$("#my-element-1")`, `$("#my-element-2")`, `$("#my-element-3") etc`.